Rigify rig is not affecting the model
New to rigging. I'm using the Rigify addon, and the Human (meta-rig). Once I move the bones in place I'm able to generate a rig. Then I selected the model then the rig and Ctrl+P and Automatic Weights, then it loads for a bit and then when I try to move the rig it moves but the model doesn't.

Human model and rig

Pose mode, center box is selected and moved, but the model is not moving at all

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Also you can try scale up the model and the rig in Edit Modes x100 times, and try to apply Rigify after.

This worked for me, thank you

Probably your Model is too high poly, for me reducing verticies which are close to yeach other worked, try it just to be shure.

if it works - later find a tutorial about how to transfer data from one rigged mesh to another.
